# Uploading file in ajax upload loop

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

I'm uploading a file using AUI ajax file upload and I want to make the same ajax request in loop once the previous response is received. What I observed is that, the next loop is getting called without receiving the response from previous request. How can make sure that, I call next loop only after receiving response?

```
var loopCount = 0;
var requiredLoops = 10;

function uploadFile(){

loopCount  = loopCount  + 1;

A.io.request('${fileUploadCSV}', {
method: 'post',   
form: {
    id: '<portlet:namespace />uploadForm',
    upload: true,
},
on: {

     complete : function(e){
   if(requiredLoops <= loopcount)
         uploadFile(); // LOOP. 

     }
```

}
});

Comment: Have tried on `success`? 
http://alloyui.com/versions/2.0.x/examples/io/real-world/

Comment: Success and failure don't get fired in upload.

Answer (score -1):

I made it work by adding uploadFile();  in setTimeout();

```
setTimeout(function(){uploadFile()}, 100);
```

Comment: No sorry but this is NOT a solution, it's only luck.

Look at https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/#uploading-files-in-an-html-form and try `end` event